# ElasticSearch: higher score for more terms present in nonanalyzed field?

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

This is a problem I've been banging my head with for the past week or so. I thought I nailed it down, but apparently not.

I have a field "tags" in my document that is currently an nonanalyzed field. When I query on this field, I want documents with MORE tags = query to return a higher score.

Example: Suppose I query the tags field for "ruby"

```
Document 1) tags: ["ruby", "ruby", "ruby"]
should score higher than:
Document 2) tags: ["ruby"]
and 
Document 3) tags: ["ruby", "python"]
```

I've tried to index my tags field as the following. But neither of them achieves what I want. In all of these instances, Document 1 never is scored the highest.

```
:tags => {:type => 'string', :index => 'not_analyzed', :include_in_all => false, :omit_norms => true}
:tags => {:type => 'string', :index => 'analyzed', :analyzer => keyword, :include_in_all => false, :omit_norms => true}
```

Comment: What query you using to query? I have a feeling `dis_max` might be the culprit.

Comment: I would guess probably a Constant Score rewrite from a prefix/fuzzy/wildcard query, personally, but yes, almost certainly the query is the problem.

Comment: Actually, the query was fine, heh :) The problem occurs when there's more than 1 shard.

Comment: In that case, look into the [types of search](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/search-type/). The standard one calculates scores a little inaccurately. Look at using a dfs search to help get the term frequency right.